# Unity Code not is Working and Animation Glitches Out When Attack Clicked Rapidly

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

Here is my code for the playerMovement script which should call certain animations directly. I am trying to implement different attack animations and have a delay equal to the animation before the player can attack again. I have tried many different delay types, Coroutines, Invoke methods, and even an external Wait function passed to a lambda function, but no matter what this stupid thing glitches out when you press attack too fast.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.AdaptivePerformance.Provider;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;
public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Initialize variables

    // Private variables
    private float moveHorizontal = 0;
    private float moveVertical = 0;
    private float attackDelay;

    // Public variables
    public float moveSpeed = 1.0f;
    public float movePenalty = 0.7f;

    // Initialize boolean variables for various action events
    private bool isAttacking = false;

    // Initialize Components
    public MobileJoystick mobileJoystick;
    private Rigidbody2D rb;
    private Animator animator;

    // Animation States
    private string currentState;
    const string IDLE = "HeroIdle";
    const string WALK_X = "WalkHoriz";
    const string WALK_Y = "WalkVertical";
    const string WALK_DIAG = "WalkDiagonal";
    const string ATTACK = "MeleeAttack";
    const string BLOCK = "ShieldBlock";
    const string THRUST = "Thrust";
    const string UPSLASH = "UpSlash";
    const string DOWNSLASH = "DownSlash";

    void Start()
    {
        // Get the players rigidbody
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();

        // Get the animator
        animator = GetComponent<Animator>();

        // Set the animation state
        ChangeAnimationState(IDLE);

    }

    void Update()
    {

        // Update movement to current moveHorizontal and moveVertical
        Vector2 movement = new Vector2(moveHorizontal, moveVertical);

        // Update Movement based on whether moving or attacking
        if (isAttacking)
        {
            // Input Movement Vectors
            moveHorizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") + mobileJoystick.InputDirection.x;
            moveVertical = Input.GetAxis("Vertical") + mobileJoystick.InputDirection.y;

            rb.velocity = movement * movePenalty;

            // Wait until animation completely finishes (gets the length of animation)
            attackDelay = animator.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).length;

            // After the waited amount of time, allow the player to move again.
            StartCoroutine(StopAttacking(attackDelay));
        }
        else
        {
            // Input Movement Vectors
            moveHorizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") + mobileJoystick.InputDirection.x;
            moveVertical = Input.GetAxis("Vertical") + mobileJoystick.InputDirection.y;

            rb.velocity = movement * moveSpeed;

            // Animate Walking for character based on direction (up/down or left/right)
            // Note these are important checks because of future mobile implementation

            // Check left / right movement is non-zero and more than vertical movement
            if (moveHorizontal != 0 && Mathf.Abs(moveHorizontal) > Mathf.Abs(moveVertical))
            {
                ChangeAnimationState(WALK_X);
            }
            // Check up / down movement is non-zero and vertical more than horizontal
            else if (moveVertical != 0 && Mathf.Abs(moveVertical) > Mathf.Abs(moveHorizontal))
            {
                ChangeAnimationState(WALK_Y);
            }
            // Check perfect diagonal movement
            else if (moveVertical != 0 && Mathf.Abs(moveVertical) == Mathf.Abs(moveHorizontal))
            {
                ChangeAnimationState(WALK_DIAG);
            }
            // Else, IDLE
            else
            {
                ChangeAnimationState(IDLE);
            }
        }
        
        // Flip the Character Left or Right based on their direction

        // If the player is moving left and the character is not flipped, flip the character
        if (moveHorizontal < 0 && transform.localScale.x > 0)
        {
            Vector3 flippedScale = transform.localScale;
            flippedScale.x = -0.05f;
            transform.localScale = flippedScale;
        }
        // If the player is moving right and the character is flipped, unflip the character
        else if (moveHorizontal > 0 && transform.localScale.x < 0)
        {
            Vector3 unflippedScale = transform.localScale;
            unflippedScale.x = 0.05f;
            transform.localScale = unflippedScale;
        }



        // Check Action animations

        // Combat and Attacking (and taking damage)

        // Get attack input
        if (!isAttacking && Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
        {
            // Set the isAttacking bool to true to prevent movement / other actions
            isAttacking = true;

            // Animate the attack
            // Check which type of attack based on player input directions
            if(moveHorizontal != 0 && Mathf.Abs(moveHorizontal) > Mathf.Abs(moveVertical))
            {
                ChangeAnimationState(THRUST);
            }
            else if(moveVertical > 0 && Mathf.Abs(moveHorizontal) < Mathf.Abs(moveVertical))
            {
                ChangeAnimationState(UPSLASH);
            }
            else if(moveVertical < 0 && Mathf.Abs(moveHorizontal) < Mathf.Abs(moveVertical))
            {
                ChangeAnimationState(DOWNSLASH);
            }
            else
            {
                ChangeAnimationState(ATTACK);
            }

        }

        // Debugging 
        Debug.Log("IsAttacking: " + isAttacking);
        Debug.Log("currentState: " + currentState);
        Debug.Log("attackDelay: " + attackDelay);
        
    }

    void ChangeAnimationState(string newState)
    {

        //stop the same animation from interrupting itself
        if (currentState == newState) return;

        //play the animation
        animator.Play(newState);

        //reassign the current state
        currentState = newState;
 
    }

    //void StopAttacking()
    //{
    //    isAttacking = false;
    //}
    IEnumerator StopAttacking(float waitTime)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(waitTime);

        isAttacking = false;
    }

}
```

I tried to move certain blocks of code around and simplify booleans thinking that it might be bogging the code down.

Comment: I would do the following, grab input, update state according input, apply state changes. Currently you are mixing everything and it makes it hard to follow. Also, introduce variables, log stuff, you should be able to get it right then. Also, don't compare floats with zero, that's plain wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful to get a description of what your "glitches" look like.

Anyway, what is definitely strange - is to run a ton of coroutines. Every single frame `Update()` will be called. And every single frame during the attack it will run `StopAttacking` coroutine. So, in case of 60 fps and attack animation duration of 0.5 sec, you will get 30 routines. And each of them will set `isAttacking` to `false` after some amount of time.

From what I see right now it will definitely cause bugs as your state will switch randomly. Start your delay right after setting `isAttack` to true and nowhere else.

Comment: Thank you I still havent figured out why it didnt work, but decided to just set my animations all to .5 seconds. Now I am having trouble implementing hitboxes and hurtboxes.